# Detect touch on whole screen

Tags: ios, iphone, uiview, uiviewcontroller, uigesturerecognizer

I want to call a method whenever a specific UIViewController is touched.

`-touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event` is a method that does what I'm looking for, exept it doesn't detect a touch on neither the statur bar, navigation bar or toolbar. How can I make a method that runs everytime the UIViewController is touched? Or in other words, the whole screen?

Comment: Why do you want to do this? Your view should only accept it's own touches.

Comment: implement touchesBegan inside AppDelegate.m but i recommend add touch events for each view controller

Comment: For full screen detection (including status bar) I think you'll need to sub class UIWindow and make it becomeFirstResponder: Override touches and handle from window sub class.

Answer (score 2):

try adding a gesture recognition. to your window object, since it's a subclass of a `uiview`.

or like @Bamsworld said. "For full screen detection (including status bar) I think you'll need to sub class `UIWindow` and make it `becomeFirstResponder:` Override touches and handle from window sub class."

Answer (score 1):

Subclass  UIApplication say MyApplication and implement the method

```
- (void)sendEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    [super sendEvent:event];
    // Do whatever you want
}
```

Then in main.m change the default implementation to

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    @autoreleasepool {
        return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, NSStringFromClass([MyApplication class]), NSStringFromClass([YourAppdelegate class]));
    }
}
```

You will get each and every action in method

```
- (void)sendEvent:(UIEvent *)event
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self.view setMultipleTouchEnabled:YES];
}

-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    // Remove old red circles on screen
    NSArray *subviews = [self.view subviews];
    for (UIView *view in subviews) {
        [view removeFromSuperview];
    }
    // Enumerate over all the touches and draw a red dot on the screen where the touches were
    [touches enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id obj, BOOL *stop) {
        // Get a single touch and it's location
        UITouch *touch = obj;
        CGPoint touchPoint = [touch locationInView:self.view];
        // Draw a red circle where the touch occurred
        UIView *touchView = [[UIView alloc] init];
        [touchView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];
        touchView.frame = CGRectMake(touchPoint.x, touchPoint.y, 30, 30);
        touchView.layer.cornerRadius = 15;
        [self.view addSubview:touchView];
        [touchView release];
    }];
}
```